# jQuery - Hide subheading if next rows contain

Tags: jquery, hide

How can I hide the subheader row if all the following rows contain a specific class. The following rows stop when another subheader is next. How can this be executed for the next subheader?

Example: Hide SUBHEADER 2 row because all the following rows contain "no".

```
<table>
<tr class='sub'>
    <td colspan='3'>SUBHEADER 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class='row yes'>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr class='row no'>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr class='sub'>
    <td colspan='3'>SUBHEADER 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class='row no'>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr class='row no'>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
<tr class='sub'>
    <td colspan='3'>SUBHEADER 3</td>
</tr>
<tr class='row yes'>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

- I tested both examples and they work but they didn't work on my enviroment. I then realized I provided an incorrect example and apologize  to Gaby and Tats for my mistake.

Comment: hide the text rows as well ? or only the `.sub` row ?

Comment: Only the subs. I made a mistake on my example and updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
// for each subheader row
$('tr.sub').each(function(){
  var self = $(this),
      // find all following rows until the next subheader
      rows = self.nextUntil('.sub'),
      // check if any of those rows contains a .no class
      hasNo = rows.find('.no').length > 0;

  // hide subheader if no .no class was found
  self.toggle(hasNo);
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/EA8AB/

---

**Update** (*after clarifications in OP*)

You need to compare if the number of following rows (*as described earlier*) equals the number of following `.no` rows..

```
// for each subheader row
$('tr.sub').each(function(){
  var self = $(this),
      // find all following rows until the next subheader
      rows = self.nextUntil('.sub'),
      // check if rows number is equal with those of them that have the .no class
      allAreNo = rows.filter('.no').length === rows.length;

  // show/hide based on whether all are .no or not
  self.toggle( !allAreNo );
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/EA8AB/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5kacR/

API: `.find` : http://api.jquery.com/find/

Rest should help your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("table tr").each(function () {
          if(!$(this).find('td.no').length)
              $(this).prev('tr').hide();
     });

 });
```